# How to calculate the highest 'high' value for each stock within a week in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame (`df`) that contains OHLC (Open, High, Low, Close) and a `'Symbol'` column. I'm trying to add a new column called `'Tgt'` which should store the highest `'High'` value for each stock within one week.

Here's the challenge: some weeks may not have data for all five weekdays, making my current approach faulty. Can someone provide a Python or Pandas solution to handle this?

Here's my current code:

```
df['Tgt'] = np.nan

previous_symbol = None
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['Symbol'][i] != previous_symbol:
        # Reset 'Tgt' when 'Symbol' changes
        df.loc[i, 'Tgt'] = np.nan
        previous_symbol = df['Symbol'][i]

    if df['DayName'][i] == 'Monday':
        start_idx = i
        end_idx = min(i + 5, len(df))
        df.loc[start_idx:end_idx, 'Tgt'] = df['High'][start_idx:end_idx].max()
```

Comment: Add a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), post what your data (minimum) looks like and what your expected output looks like

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `.groupby(week)` in combination with `.transform('max')`.

- `groupby()`: Groups the data by a colum or a list of columns
- `transform('max')`: Assigns the maximum of each group to all the rows (in contrast to `groupby().max()`, which only keeps one line per row and assigns the maximum)

Your idea of counting the weekdays is good but lacks flexibility. I suggest calculating the week in a different way. Instead of relying solely on Mondays to mark the beginning of a new week, you can track the weekdays and increment the week number whenever an earlier weekday appears for the same symbol:

```py
# Initialize columns and dictionary to keep track of the last seen day for each symbol
df['Week'] = np.nan
df['Tgt'] = np.nan
last_seen_day = {}

# List of weekdays to check the order
week_days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    symbol = row['Symbol']
    current_day = row['DayName']
    
    # If it's a new symbol, initialize its last seen day and week number
    if symbol not in last_seen_day:
        last_seen_day[symbol] = current_day
        df.at[idx, 'Week'] = 1
    else:
        # Check if the current day is earlier in the week than the last seen day
        if week_days.index(current_day) < week_days.index(last_seen_day[symbol]):
            df.at[idx, 'Week'] = df.at[idx - 1, 'Week'] + 1  # Increment the week number
        else:
            df.at[idx, 'Week'] = df.at[idx - 1, 'Week']  # Otherwise, it's the same week
            
        last_seen_day[symbol] = current_day  # Update the last seen day
```

With this new column you can group by the symbol and the week and get the "highest high" of each:

```
df['Tgt'] = df.groupby(['Week', 'Symbol'])['High'].transform('max')
```

**Full executable example:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample data: Notice that AAPL has no Monday in the second "week"
data = {'Symbol': ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'MSFT', 'MSFT'],
        'DayName': ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday'],
        'High': [100, 105, 103, 108, 110, 115, 50, 55]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Week'] = np.nan
df['Tgt'] = np.nan
last_seen_day = {}

week_days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    symbol = row['Symbol']
    current_day = row['DayName']
    
    if symbol not in last_seen_day:
        last_seen_day[symbol] = current_day
        df.at[idx, 'Week'] = 1
    else:
        if week_days.index(current_day) < week_days.index(last_seen_day[symbol]):
            df.at[idx, 'Week'] = df.at[idx - 1, 'Week'] + 1  # Increment the week number
        else:
            df.at[idx, 'Week'] = df.at[idx - 1, 'Week']  # Otherwise, it's the same week
            
        last_seen_day[symbol] = current_day  # Update the last seen day

df['Tgt'] = df.groupby(['Week', 'Symbol'])['High'].transform('max')

print(df)
```

| Symbol | DayName | High | Week | Tgt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | Monday | 100 | 1 | 110 |
| AAPL | Tuesday | 105 | 1 | 110 |
| AAPL | Wednesday | 103 | 1 | 110 |
| AAPL | Thursday | 108 | 1 | 110 |
| AAPL | Friday | 110 | 1 | 110 |
| AAPL | Tuesday | 115 | 2 | 115 |
| AAPL | Monday | 112 | 3 | 112 |
| MSFT | Wednesday | 50 | 1 | 55 |
| MSFT | Thursday | 55 | 1 | 55 |

Comment: This has a problem if any week has less than 5d then it will consider next day in same week. For eg if in a week there is no Thursday then it will consider next monday in that week and start week from tuesday. I don't want like that I want to create highest tgt for that week only

Comment: Sorry for that, I adjusted my answer. However, do you have a column with a full date and not only with the week days? That would make it a lot easier!

Comment: @MoxarthOswal Does the new code satisfy your requirements? It looks up whether the current day is actually before day last seen and if so assumes a new week has started.